# How to calculate average response of 100 threads in bean shell sampler from a .csv file and write it to a .html file

Tags: jmeter

I have Response data of each thread in a .csv file. Now once all the threads run and saved response result in a .csv file or .jtl how to calculate the average of all the thread response and how to calculate min and max of those responses in beanshell and write the average , min and max result in a .html file through beanshell sampler

Comment: Why would you want to do those calculations in BeanShell sampler? I mean there are tools that do it for you already: from creating summary report using JTL you have, to fancy options like grafana, to Excel graphs/functions... or even awk/powershell.  So what does BeanShell sampler do that none of the other options does?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be going for [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) which can export [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) in CSV format. The relevant command line would be something like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD--generate-csv test.csv --input-jtl results.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

You can install JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

---

If you still want to go for scripting make sure to choose the most performing scripting option which is [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223). Example Groovy code to calculate min, max and avg values from the CSV file would be something like:

```
def csvFile = new File('test.csv')
log.info('--- CSV File contents ---')
log.info(csvFile.text)
log.info('-------------------------')

def responseTimes = csvFile.readLines().each {}.collect {responseTime -> responseTime as long}
log.info('Avg:' + responseTimes.sum() / responseTimes.size())
log.info('Max: ' + responseTimes.max())
log.info('Min: ' + responseTimes.min())
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Calculate Average Min And Max]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. But how to capture only Response data of all threads and calculate and write the calculated result in a .csv file ?

Comment: JMeter already **does it**, response time is the first column of the .jtl results file, just [run your test in command-line non-GUI  mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like `jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.csv` and open the `result.csv` with any text editor. You can configure JMeter to store only response times in the .jtl file by amending [Results File Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config).  I wouldn't recommend writing a file using scripting as in case of many threads they can clash

Comment: ok. My scenario is i have an api and i am checking 50, 100,500 and 1000 users with 1 rampup count. so i need to calculate min, max and avg of 50 threads alone and 100 alone and so on publish the result through jenkins in email. like
            min   max   avg
50
100
500
1000

in mail report

Comment: but .jtl file contains result of all the threads say 50, 100, 500 and 1000 users i would not be able to generate min max and average for  each